# How can I achieve this responsive layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 3 elements: A, B and C.

On mobile, I'd like to have this:

```
AA
AA
BB
BB
CC
CC
```

On desktop, I'd like to have this:

```
AABB
AABB
CCBB
CCBB
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried Bootstrap grid system?

Comment: I'd prefer not to add Bootstrap to my dependencies. Isn't there a clean CSS solution?

Comment: What have you already tried, and how does your HTML look?

Comment: @BenM: Currently this component works only on desktop, so I have a <div> that contains A and C and I have a <div> that contains B. Both of these divs are placed side-by-side using a flexbox and A and C are placed above each other with a second flexbox. I don't think I will be able to turn this into a responsive design though.

Comment: @MauritsvanAltvorst, Yes you can create your own CSS solutions using `@media` query [Click Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) .

Comment: @AhmedTagAmer How can I use a `@media` query to move the B div out of the A and C divs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've tagged this [flexbox](/questions/tagged/flexbox) but the layout you want is 2-d so you should use a [css-grid](/questions/tagged/css-grid).

Replace the class in the example below with a media query.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => document.body.classList.toggle("desktop"));
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#a {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  grid-area: grid-a;
}

#b {
  background: green;
  color: black;
  grid-area: grid-b;
}

#c {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  grid-area: grid-c;
}

.desktop main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto-fit auto-fit;
  grid-template-rows: auto-fit auto-fit;
  grid-template-areas: "grid-a grid-b" "grid-c grid-b";
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="a">A</div>
  <div id="b">B</div>
  <div id="c">C</div>
</main>

<button>toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can reorganize your markup you could use the approach below.

```css
#wrap {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}

.AA, .CC {
  background: gray;
}

.BB {
  background: lightgray;
}

/* use media query to style for desktop */
.desktop {
  overflow: auto;
}

.desktop > div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.desktop .AA, 
.desktop .CC {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
}

.desktop .BB {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<p><button onClick="document.getElementById('wrap').classList.toggle('desktop')">Toggle Layout</button></p>

<div id="wrap" class="desktop">
  <div class="AA">AA</div>
  <div class="AA">AA</div>
  <div class="BB">BB</div>
  <div class="BB">BB</div>
  <div class="CC">CC</div>
  <div class="CC">CC</div>
  <div class="BB">BB</div>
  <div class="BB">BB</div>
</div>
```